# webview shows everytime the content from the last loadurl() method

Tags: android, webview

i have the Problem that i load a website with the loadDataWithBaseURL method. There i load a prepared internetsite in a webview. if i go back in my previous activity and start the webview activity it loads the same prepared website with loadDataWithBaseURL() method but i get a webview with twice the content. For example Hello World and the second Hello World.
My Code is the followed:

```
 package de.http.test;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.webkit.WebBackForwardList;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class WebviewActivity extends Activity {

    WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.mywebview);         
        Bundle bundle= this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String param1 = bundle.getString("Weburl");

        getDetailWebsite(param1);   

        webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        loadWebview();

    }

    public void loadWebview()
    {       
        webview.clearView();        

        webview.loadDataWithBaseURL("http://branchenportal-schlitz.de", HttpHelperClass.htmlDetailWebsiteCode, "text/html", "UTF-8", HttpHelperClass.htmlDetailWebsiteCode);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && webview.canGoBack()) {
            webview.goBack();   

            WebBackForwardList mWebBackForwardList = webview.copyBackForwardList();
            String historyUrl = mWebBackForwardList.getItemAtIndex(mWebBackForwardList.getCurrentIndex()).getUrl();

            if(historyUrl.contains("<html>"))
            {               
                loadWebview();
            }

            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }

    private void getDetailWebsite(String url)
    {   
        try{            
            HttpHelperClass.executeHttpGetDetailWebsite(url,this);

        }catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();           
        }
    }

    private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {

            if(url.contains("branchenportal-schlitz.de"))
            {
                view.clearHistory();
            }
            super.onPageFinished(view, url);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {

        webview.clearCache(true);       
        webview.clearView();
        webview.clearHistory();
        webview.destroy();      
        super.onStop();     
    }


}
```

Is there anybody who knows what iam doing wrong?
Thanks in advance.
With regards

Answer (score 0):

OK well to trouble shoot this I would start by getting rid of (commenting out) all of your code below  public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event).  Then you can see if its in your onCreate or not. But that's up to.

```
  @Override
 public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.buttons);
     wb = new WebView(this);
     wb.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
     wb.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient()); 

     final String urlToLoad = "http://www.yourWebsite.com";

     wb.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
     wb.loadUrl(urlToLoad);
 }
```

start here then start adding your extra code back in.